# Jetty client http error code 412

Tags: http, jsf-2, http-headers, viewstate, jetty-9

I am accessing one website (I am hiding origin website name as it is against the policy) using browser and jetty/apache httpclient.

The website works fine with web browser.

Using api I am able to login into website,gets the session cookie JSESSIONID and home page html content. But after that when I submit any form or call the links from html I receive the HTTP error code 412(Pre condition failed).

I understand this error is due problem in client header. I set all the headers from browser(checked using inspect element in chrome browser). Still I have the same error.

I am not able to track down which header is causing the problem.

Here is the Header from browser 
**Request Headers**

- Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
- Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
- Cache-Control:max-age=0
- Connection:keep-alive
- Content-Length:318
- Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Cookie:language=en_IN;     __gads=ID=14c64d8f9fd7de54:T=1424658276:S=ALNI_Mba1kvJO4mLo7R-T2jUJE9zCYck5A; SLB_Cookie=ffffffff09461c2d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a422971; JSESSIONID=36m4Oo6dCML_Wvx-Wgmm9rtLh9mbURxnZhWIVwg-zHaNzFQeUt9C!-1989013783; _ga=GA1.3.379900459.1428120216
- Host:www.irctc.co.in
- Origin:https://www.example.com
- Referer:https://www.example.com/context/home
- Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36

Same header I am setting from jetty client.

```
Request request = httpClient.newRequest(url);
    request.method(HttpMethod.POST);
    request.agent(USER_AGENT);
        request.accept("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.header(HttpHeader.REFERER,"https://www.example.com/context/home");
    request.header(HttpHeader.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");
    request.header(HttpHeader.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
    request.header(HttpHeader.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=0");
    request.header(HttpHeader.CONNECTION, "keep-alive");
    request.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.header(HttpHeader.HOST, "www.example.com);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
    request.param(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"),    URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(content)){
            content+="&";
        }

        content+=URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");
}
request.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH, ""+content.length());
```

I see JSESSIONID and SLB_Cookie are present in the request. Since the website is out of our control  I really can not track what is the issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Any pointers to resolve the issue on client side is appreciated. is there any way we can make sure which header causing this issue.

Comment: Looks like for post request content-length is not required explicitly. So it does not seems to be issue with content-length

Comment: I see this issue may be with JSF viewstate parameters. The form which I am submitting contains javax.faces.ViewState hidden parameter. If remove this parameter from the submission, I get the same page back in response. With this parameter I gets 412.  Still question is same form submisison works fine with browser but not from  jetty/apache  httpclient

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Issue with the form parameters value. I was sending encoded values where were encoded by jetty client again